# deny access to svn directories

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, svn

i've got a project which is being checked out directly into public_html folder. What would be the best way to deny access to ".svn" directories and ideally hide them completely (that is, return 404, not 403)?

Comment: Export to deploy, don't checkout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RedirectMatch 404 /\.svn(/|$)
```